# Twisted integration test

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I'm trying to make a end to end connection test using Trial.
For this purpose I created a mockserver which implements the generic methods, connectionMade and connectionLost.

For the client-side I reused the real modules because I wanna test their operation.The problem comes when I try to established a connection.

It only works when I run the reactor.run method which I know can't be used.

How twisted handles the test reactor? I mean, it's only needed run the reactor.listen method, from the server-side, and the reactor.connect method from the client-side for established a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `Deferred` from your `test_` method, which is what tells the reactor to run - firing that `Deferred` then tells the reactor to stop.

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.0.0/core/howto/trial.html explains how to do this.